# Why there is black appearing when I imported the skin?

Tags: modeling, texturing

I already adjusted the UV map. I am not sure why the monkey face turned black while the body is fine. [image]

Comment: hello could you please pack the images and share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: There are two main reasons this could be happening. A, the normal map off screen is crazy, or B, the wrong material is assigned to the face.